# Python Scrapy scraping giving garbage values

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to practice scraping in a table the table belongs to css class "table" and that table has many tr and each tr has 3 td first td is for name second td is for address third td (if present is for phone number) i need the name, address and phone from each "tr" but for some reason if set a selector as 'td ::text' (text from all tds inside each tr) works fine but i need name, address and phone separately

so i use xpath and do this for the 1st td for name 2nd td for address and if exist 3rd td for phone number

```
            NAME_SELECTOR = '//tr/td[1]/text()'
            ADDRESS_SELECTOR = '//tr/td[2]/text()'
            PHONE = '//tr/td[3]/text()'

            yield {
                'name': np.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'address': np.xpath(ADDRESS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'phone': np.xpath(PHONE).extract_first(),
            }
```

but this gives garbage value like this[image: THE IMAGE WITH DATA]

why this garbage value ? it should work code is very simple website is very simple too(thats why i choose it for practice)

here is the whole code

```
try:
    import scrapy
except ImportError:
    print "\nERROR IMPORTING THE NECESSARY LIBRARIES\n"

class NameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'name spider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.locatefamily.com/Street-Lists/Australia/index-1.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = 'table.table tr'
        for np in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            NAME_SELECTOR = '//tr/td[1]/text()'
            ADDRESS_SELECTOR = '//tr/td[2]/text()'
            PHONE = '//tr/td[3]/text()'

            yield {
                'name': np.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'address': np.xpath(ADDRESS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'phone': np.xpath(PHONE).extract_first(),
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` at the beginning of XPath always reference the root document, that's why you got the same values in every iteration regardless of what `np` variable references at the moment. You need to add `.` to explicitly tell that you mean the XPath to be relative to current context element :

```
for np in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
    NAME_SELECTOR = './/tr/td[1]/text()'
    ADDRESS_SELECTOR = './/tr/td[2]/text()'
    PHONE = './/tr/td[3]/text()'

    yield {
        'name': np.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'address': np.xpath(ADDRESS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        'phone': np.xpath(PHONE).extract_first(),
    }
```

Comment: but i had to write it like this './/td[1]/text()'    './/tr/td[1]/text()' was returning none for some reason

Comment: I see. If `td` is direct child of `tr`, then simply `td[1]`, `td[2]`, `td[3]` i.e without `.//` should do...

Comment: Also, notice that `/text()` only returns text nodes that is direct child of current element, but part of the names are nested in `<a>` element. I don't have scrapy to test, but the following XPath works using `lxml` : `string(td[1])`. The XPath should return concatenation of all text nodes within `td[1]`.